# How to treat entries in lua table as strings?

Tags: string, variables, lua, lua-table

The following code produces nothing as a,b,c are nil.

```
s={a,b,c}
for _,v in ipairs(s) do 
  print(v)
end
```

The following code

```
s={"a","b","c"}
for _,v in ipairs(s) do 
  print(v)
end
```

produces

a

b

c

This is obvious as "a", "b", "c" are strings. I want to get same output as  that of second code when s is declared as {a,b,c}. In short I want to treat every entry in table s as string. Is there a way to do this in Lua? I know that this is strange question, but I need it while working with lua and LaTeX for some purpose.

Comment: `setmetatable(_G,{__index=function(t,k)if type(k)=="string" and k:match"^[%w_]+$" then return k end end})`

Comment: Thanks. It works great. Kindly post this as answer so that I can accept it as answer.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing; just keep in mind that this change could break code elsewhere if it assumes uninitialized globals to be `nil`.

Comment: Also the simpler `setmetatable(_G,{__index=function(t,k) return k end})`.

Comment: Is there a  better wayout? This works in lua but not with luaTeX. Refer to the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537582/error-when-metatable-is-set-for-global-environment-in-lua-latex